# Remove double quotes from CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I would like to clean a CSV file which has in the middle of a string double quotes by removing all quotation marks inside the csv.
as an example: Ana are "mere". I would like that the quotes are removed so that I will have Ana are mere

I am trying to replace the " with a space but I cannot w and r a csv at the same time. How can I clean the data?

```
import csv
with open('/var/lib/neo4j/import/MRCONSO.csv',"r+",encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    for data in csv_file:
        data = [d.replace('"', '') for d in data]
```

I expect that the CSV structure will not change only the quotes will be removed.

Comment: Presumably you do realise that removing quotes from a csv file can alter the way the csv is parsed?

Comment: my csv has a fieldterminator \t , I tought is not going to be a problem if i remove all quotes

Comment: Cool, as long as you're aware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't have to iterate lines, you can just read the full content, use `replace` as you did, and write the new content:

```py
with open('/var/lib/neo4j/import/MRCONSO.csv', "r+", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    content = csv_file.read()

with open('/var/lib/neo4j/import/MRCONSO.csv', "w+", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    csv_file.write(content.replace('"', ''))
```

Comment: it won't work if columns had values with commas.

>for example
>col1, col2
>"mere", "me,re"

>after transformation, you have
>col1, col2
>mere, me, re

Comment: if you are importing the csv into databases. I would suggest to no to transform the data per the importing. then transform data within the database.

Answer (score -1):

You can use pandas:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv',header=None)
df.replace('"', '', inplace=True, regex=True)
df.to_csv("file.csv",header=False, index=False)
```